# Python grammar question (string with list)

Tags: python

as I studying other's python code,

I got the code as below.

Could you explain what it means.

This is part of the code that show the number only with 1,2, 4.
(For example, 1->1, 2->2, 3-> 4, 4 -> 11, etc.)

```
answer = '124'[n%3] + answer
```

Comment: Which particular part of that code do you not understand? Do you known what the `%` operator does? What indexing a string does? What using `+` between strings does?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> answer = 'hello'
>>> n = 3
>>> answer = '124'[n%3] + answer 
    # '124'[1] => '1' Here it does string indexing and concatenation (+)
>>> answer
'1hello'
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more like to attract upvotes.

Comment: Sure. Actually OP asked, what that single line code does. And I have mentioned what it does in my code comment section.